# How to disable errors in VS Code (gopls) when writing code in go1.18beta?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Want to use `go1.18beta` for its generics feature to handle errors in a central function.

Error handling function example

```golang
func HandleError[T any](t T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return t
}
```

The first error thrown is

`expected '(', found '['s`

The second error thrown is

`not enough arguments in call to HandleError (compiler) (WrongArgCount)`

I am aware that gopls is of `go1.17` and that's why it's throwing errors but is there any way to disable these errors as we do in typescript?

Comment: You can disable `gopls` with `go.useLanguageServer: false`

Comment: That helps in hiding the error but I need the language server for other files/functions.

Comment: Try to install `gopls` with `go1.18beta` support.

Comment: I am unable to find `gopls` with `go1.18beta` support. I tried their git repo but there is no branch for 1.18beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a gopls with 1.18 go as described here:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/advanced.md#working-with-generic-code